# Помогите исправить ошибку при установке ip2geotools

Tags: python

Полный код ошибки

```
Building wheel for maxminddb (setup.py) ... error 
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error 

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [94 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      The [wheel] section is deprecated. Use [bdist_wheel] instead.
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\maxminddb
      copying maxminddb\const.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\maxminddb
      copying maxminddb\decoder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\maxminddb
      copying maxminddb\errors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\maxminddb
      copying maxminddb\file.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\maxminddb
      copying maxminddb\reader.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\maxminddb
      copying maxminddb\types.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\maxminddb
      copying maxminddb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\maxminddb
      running egg_info
      writing maxminddb.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to maxminddb.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing top-level names to maxminddb.egg-info\top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'maxminddb.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      warning: manifest_maker: MANIFEST.in, line 2: path 'tests/' cannot end with '/'
     
      adding license file 'LICENSE'
      writing manifest file 'maxminddb.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      copying maxminddb\extension.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\maxminddb
      copying maxminddb\py.typed -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\maxminddb
      running build_ext
      building 'maxminddb.extension' extension
      Traceback (most recent call last): 
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pekvybqv\maxminddb_92be2297d38444db975e5d8316e7dd00\setup.py", line 146, in <
module>
          run_setup(True)
        File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pekvybqv\maxminddb_92be2297d38444db975e5d8316e7dd00\setup.py", line 101, in r
un_setup
          setup(
        File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 153, in setup       
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
        File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
          dist.run_commands()
        File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 299, in run
          self.run_command('build')
        File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
          self.run_command(cmd_name)
        File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command 
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pekvybqv\maxminddb_92be2297d38444db975e5d8316e7dd00\setup.py", line 44, in ru
n
          build_ext.run(self)
        File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 340, in run
          self.build_extensions()
        File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 449, in build_extensions  
          self._build_extensions_serial()
        File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 474, in _build_extensions_
serial
          self.build_extension(ext)
        File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pekvybqv\maxminddb_92be2297d38444db975e5d8316e7dd00\setup.py", line 50, in bu
ild_extension
          build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)
        File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 529, in build_extension   
          objects = self.compiler.compile(sources,
        File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 323, in compile
          self.initialize()
        File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 220, in initialize
          vc_env = _get_vc_env(plat_spec)
        File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 316, in msvc14_get_vc_en
v
          return _msvc14_get_vc_env(plat_spec)
        File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 268, in _msvc14_get_vc_e
nv
          vcvarsall, vcruntime = _msvc14_find_vcvarsall(plat_spec)
        File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 223, in _msvc14_find_vcv
arsall
          _, best_dir = _msvc14_find_vc2017()
        File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 193, in _msvc14_find_vc2
017
          path = subprocess.check_output([
        File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 420, in check_output
          return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
        File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\run\__init__.py", line 145, in __new__
          process = cls.create_process(command, stdin, cwd=cwd, env=env, shell=shell)
        File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\run\__init__.py", line 121, in create_process     
          shlex.split(command),
        File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\shlex.py", line 315, in split
          return list(lex)
        File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\shlex.py", line 300, in __next__
          token = self.get_token() 
        File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\shlex.py", line 109, in get_token
          raw = self.read_token()
        File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\shlex.py", line 140, in read_token
          nextchar = self.instream.read(1)
      AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'read'
      [end of output]
 
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for maxminddb
  Running setup.py clean for maxminddb
Failed to build maxminddb 
Installing collected packages: maxminddb, lxml, lazy-object-proxy, keyring, isort, importlib-metadata, h11, docutils, dill, cssselect, colorama,
 chardet, bleach, autopep8, async-generator, wsproto, trio, tqdm, requests-toolbelt, readme-renderer, pyquery, pip-review, astroid, twine, trio-
websocket, pylint, geoip2, selenium, ip2geotools
  Running setup.py install for maxminddb ... error 
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error 

  × Running setup.py install for maxminddb did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [95 lines of output]
      running install
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\maxminddb
      copying maxminddb\const.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\maxminddb
      copying maxminddb\decoder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\maxminddb
      copying maxminddb\errors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\maxminddb
      copying maxminddb\file.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\maxminddb
      copying maxminddb\reader.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\maxminddb
      copying maxminddb\types.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\maxminddb
      copying maxminddb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\maxminddb
      running egg_info
      writing maxminddb.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to maxminddb.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing top-level names to maxminddb.egg-info\top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'maxminddb.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      warning: manifest_maker: MANIFEST.in, line 2: path 'tests/' cannot end with '/'
     
      adding license file 'LICENSE'
      writing manifest file 'maxminddb.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      copying maxminddb\extension.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\maxminddb
      copying maxminddb\py.typed -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\maxminddb
      running build_ext
      building 'maxminddb.extension' extension
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pekvybqv\maxminddb_92be2297d38444db975e5d8316e7dd00\setup.py", line 146, in <
module>
          run_setup(True)
        File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pekvybqv\maxminddb_92be2297d38444db975e5d8316e7dd00\setup.py", line 101, in r
un_setup
          setup(
        File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 153, in setup       
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
        File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
          dist.run_commands()
        File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run   
          return orig.install.run(self)
        File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 568, in run
          self.run_command('build')
        File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
          self.run_command(cmd_name)
        File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command) 
        File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pekvybqv\maxminddb_92be2297d38444db975e5d8316e7dd00\setup.py", line 44, in ru
n
          build_ext.run(self)
        File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 340, in run
          self.build_extensions()
        File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 449, in build_extensions  
          self._build_extensions_serial()
        File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 474, in _build_extensions_
serial
          self.build_extension(ext)
        File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pekvybqv\maxminddb_92be2297d38444db975e5d8316e7dd00\setup.py", line 50, in bu
ild_extension
          build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)
        File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 529, in build_extension   
          objects = self.compiler.compile(sources,
        File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 323, in compile
          self.initialize()
        File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 220, in initialize
          vc_env = _get_vc_env(plat_spec)
        File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 316, in msvc14_get_vc_en
v
          return _msvc14_get_vc_env(plat_spec)
        File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 268, in _msvc14_get_vc_e
nv
          vcvarsall, vcruntime = _msvc14_find_vcvarsall(plat_spec)
        File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 223, in _msvc14_find_vcv
arsall
          _, best_dir = _msvc14_find_vc2017()
        File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 193, in _msvc14_find_vc2
017
          path = subprocess.check_output([
        File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 420, in check_output
          return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
        File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\run\__init__.py", line 145, in __new__
          process = cls.create_process(command, stdin, cwd=cwd, env=env, shell=shell)
        File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\run\__init__.py", line 121, in create_process     
          shlex.split(command),
        File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\shlex.py", line 315, in split
          return list(lex)
        File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\shlex.py", line 300, in __next__
          token = self.get_token()
        File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\shlex.py", line 109, in get_token
          raw = self.read_token()
        File "C:\Users\Professional\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\shlex.py", line 140, in read_token
          nextchar = self.instream.read(1)
      AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'read'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> maxminddb

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

Comment: Попробуйте на более старом питоне поставить, может с 3.10 оно не очень совместимо.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, то возникают ошибки при сборке пакета, то есть при компиляции. Не знаю, насколько это поможет, но попробуйте скачать файл whl вот [отсюда](https://pypi.org/project/ip2geotools/#files) и установить локально с помощью pip install "имя_пакета".

Опять же, оговорюсь, что не знаю, насколько это поможет, но у меня иногда при установке тоже возникали такие ошибки, особенно в Windows. Иногда помогала ручная установка.